# Access google compute engine from google app engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

I have an instance running on the Compute Engine which uses Torch to predict objects in images. I wanted to make a simple web interface using which a user can upload an image, the image is sent to the server(compute engine), the objects are predicted and the list is returned back to the user. In my compute engine (Ubuntu 14.04) this line of code is used to predict objects in images. (All the other setup has been already done in the compute engine.)

```
th eval.lua -model /path/to/model -image_folder /path/to/image/directory -num_images 10
```

I want to call this line from the web app and pass the image to the image folder and get back the list of objects. How do I go about it?

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate but the mechanisms could very well be described in the same question.

Comment: @konqi exact duplicate, no diff at all (except title), you could compare, symbol by symbol

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Okay okay... i was looking at the heading which inversed the communication flow.